# Macbook Pro A1706, Glass Screen Repair (not the LCD)

Tags: hardware, screen, repair, touch-bar

So recently I broke the display of my Macbook by closing the lid with an item inside. I have repaired the LCD myself, however, when I was making the repair I cracked the glass screen cover.

Just wondering if anyone knows where I could buy a new glass screen cover (13", touchbar model). I've had a look around but I can only seem to find listings for both the LCD and the glass...

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

**You have to replace the whole assembly.**

The LCD and the glass are glued together so it's next to impossible for the average repair person to separate the two. (Technically, they *can* be unglued, but it requires specialized equipment).

These are tough to source and expensive (PN# [661-05095](http://radnex.us/MBP-2016-13-Retina-Display)).  You may have to get it from a Apple repair shop or surf eBay for a "parts" MBP and salvage the screen.